# finding out if a text input includes a specific text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

what is the best way of finding out if a text input includes a specific text with JQuery?

For example, how can I find out and return a Boolean result if `$('#poo').val()` includes ***airport***?

**EDIT**

Here is the solution to my problem thanks to @Niklas;

```
var IsbtFortxtPropertyHotelNameOn = false;
$('#<%: txtPropertyHotelName.ClientID %>').keyup(function() { 

    if (/airport/i.test(this.value) && !IsbtFortxtPropertyHotelNameOn) { 
        $('#<%: txtPropertyHotelName.ClientID %>').btOn();
        IsbtFortxtPropertyHotelNameOn = true;
    } else if(IsbtFortxtPropertyHotelNameOn && !/airport/i.test(this.value)) {
        $('#<%: txtPropertyHotelName.ClientID %>').btOff();
        IsbtFortxtPropertyHotelNameOn = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have control over the case-sensitivity, you could use regex:

```
if (/airport/i.test(this.value)) alert('true');
```

It becomes especially useful if you need to check for multiple variables instead of just airport:

```
if (/(airport|station|docks)/i.test(this.value)) alert('true');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/tHLdD/

Comment: Nice touch there. the best one. I am gonna use it blur event instead of keyup. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

normally you'd do it with either *indexOf* or *split* functions, e.g.

```
$("#textInput").val().split("specifictext").length > 0
```

there's also [Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> ***Description**: Select all elements that contain the specified text.*

which serves a slightly different purpose but may be of use to you

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#elementId").val().indexOf("airport") != -1) {
    //Contains "airport"
}
```

The JavaScript `indexOf` function returns the index of the first occurence of the specified string. If the string is not found, it returns `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know if it's the best way.. but

```
function findInpWithTxt(txt) {
    var t = null;
    $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(txt) >= 0) {
            t = this;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return t;
}
```

this will return the input if found, null if not

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the update, for me he was looking for all of them.